# Facebook app not working in mobile

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api, mobile, facebook-php-sdk

I have created a new facebook app at : https://apps.facebook.com/inboxcupid/

For some reason when I'm trying to open the app in mobile it will not load. I;m getting an error message from Facebook stating: "The mobile version of the app 'Inboxcupid' is unavailable because it is misconfigured for mobile access."

I have tried everything to turn this around but couldn't.

Can anybody help me?

Thanks.

Comment: Go to setting of the app in FB. You can see an option to add the mobile platform. Add that and then try.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Facebook Apps are not mobile compatible. You'll need to setup a mobile compatible website (which has a relevant setting on the Application Settings Page - look for "Mobile Site URL"), or create a mobile app on iOS / Android / Windows Mobile (separate settings for each).